# Error installing petsc with homebrew

Tags: homebrew, osx-yosemite, petsc

I tried installing `petsc` with homebrew on OSX 10.10.1 with:

```
$brew install petsc
```

I get one error installing one dependency:

```
==> Installing petsc dependency: hypre
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/petsc/externalpackages/hypre-2.9.0b.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/hypre-2.9.0b.tar.gz
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: aaf8354437be38aa2fbcc944ab64d464a5b39207
Actual: bd7ca57e45badf322b9c9cb970403c191287da72
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/hypre-2.9.0b.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

So I tried installing `hypre` with homebrew

```
$brew install hypre
```

and I didn't get any error
    ==> Summary
      /usr/local/Cellar/hypre/2.9.0b_1: 48 files, 4.5M

Finally, I modified the `petsc` formula and commented out this line

```
 depends_on "hypre"        => ["with-mpi", :recommended]
```

Now I can install `petsc` but it doesn't work

```
configure:12901: WARNING: No PETSC_DIR set - trying to autodetect 
configure:12919: Using PETSC_DIR=/usr/local
configure:12966: mpif90 -o conftest -ffast-math -frecord-marker=4  -DHAVE_NUMPY -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -fno-realloc-lhs -ffree-line-length-none -ffixed-line-length-none  -O3      conftest.F90 -lparmetis -lmetis -llapack -lpthread -lm -lstdc++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -u _PyMac_Error /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../.. -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../.. -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm >&5
conftest.F90:3.30:

                      use petsc
                          1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'petsc.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to set the environment variable PETSC_DIR; see `brew info petsc` for details. The caveats at the bottom were printed after installation. Instead of modifying the `petsc` formula you could have passed `--without-hypre` to `brew install`. If you could report the SHA mismatch to https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science they'd appreciate it, though.

Comment: `brew install hypre` works, but `brew install hypre --with-mpi` doesn't ... `--with-mpi` is actually giving the error

Comment: Only because the hypre tarball isn't being retrieved unless you specify `--with-mpi`; with the default options, it installs Homebrew's binary package instead.